# Android Runtime Error while executing Application on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have just started learning Android Development.

## While running my android application getting following error code.

```js
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.karan.newapp, PID: 3385
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.karan.newapp/com.example.karan.newapp.mainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3758)
                      at com.example.karan.newapp.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:26)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

---

Here is a Sample of my Code.
Please help me out on below.

```js
package com.example.karan.newapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.graphics.Color;
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myLayout.addView(myButton);
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        myButton.setText(R.string.myButton);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails =
               new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
        buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        myLayout.addView(myButton,buttonDetails);
        setContentView(myLayout);
    }
}
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: There are **WAY** too many things wrong here. Read up on basics of Android app development again.

Comment: Also, the `Javascript` tag doesn't belong to this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karan, it looks like you problem might be on the line

```
   myLayout.addView(myButton,buttonDetails);
```

You have already added the button to the layout prior to this.

```
   myLayout.addView(myButton);
```

It is good to know how to create a layout programatically, but I would strongly suggest that you do this in XML instead, and do things in code only if you need to make changes  at runtime.  Also, when you use XML, you get the design editor where you can visually see how it will look.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code has some complexity for just a basic activity
I'll point out some errors, but it is best to learn some basics before working with android studio.

1. your java class name started with small case letter `mainActivity` , it is not best to use that, always use a capital letter at beginning of your class name eg: `MainActivity`.
2. To link your layout file to java class using `setContentView();` , try to use the id of the layout to call it, it is the best practice. eg : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.
3. as your error indicates `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity` , there is a problem related to your activity file. i think you are declaring and using the button before `setContentView();` , we can declare and use buttons and other codes in our java class after the `setContentView();` so that it will display the activity correctly.

eg:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        ....
        ....
          }
```

4. In order to change the background color of layout, buttons, and other attributes like giving button name from string etc, it is best to make the changes that in its corresponding XML layout resource file

the one you used :

```
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    myButton.setText(R.string.myButton);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails =
           new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
```

the easiest and more proper way is :

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/stringname"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed one line from my code

myLayout.addView(myButton);

And it worked fine

Actually issue was there because same button object was asked to display on screen twice.